# Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running? Error in working in Gitlab CI/CD pipeline

Tags: docker, gitlab, pipeline, cicd, amazon-ecr

```
 aws_ecr:
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cloud-deploy/aws-base:latest
  

  stage: build

  script:
  

    - aws ecr get-login-password | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin 51234567.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com

    - docker build    --build-arg IMAGE_TAG=$IMAGE_TAG  -t $IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG .
```

when I run in registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cloud-deploy/aws-base:latest image I couldnt run docker commands . like I couldnt build and push images  .I got error  message like this.

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

Comment: Docker should be installed inside your GitLab runner, is it the case for you ?

Comment: I don't think aws-base was intednded to be used as a DinD image.
I see you are trying to build and publish an image from the aws-base and that is not the purpose of the image.

I suggest building the image in the way you usually do it and one option would be to maybe pipe the token from an docker run command to the docker login command

`docker run -i -e AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=<region> -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<id> -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<key> registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cloud-deploy/aws-base:latest aws ecr get-login-password | docker login --username <username> --password-stdin <registry>`